# PubSub not re-delivering message after ack deadline

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have two subscriber pointing to same subscription of topic use case. 
As per document pub sub redeliver the message if subscriber took more time than Acknowledgement deadline to acknowledge the message.

I have configure the default value which is 10 sec. But processing takes approx ~ 1 min to complete and acknowledge.
Below is my sample code

````
public class SubscribeAsyncExample {

    private Subscriber subscriber = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
        String projectId = "your-project-id";
        String subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";
        subscribeAsyncExample(projectId, subscriptionId);
    }

    public void subscribeAsyncExample(String projectId, String subscriptionId) {
        ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);

        // Instantiate an asynchronous message receiver.
        MessageReceiver receiver = (PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) -> {
            // Handle incoming message, then ack the received message.
            System.out.println("Id: " + message.getMessageId());
            System.out.println("Data: " + message.getData().toStringUtf8());
            int sleepingTime = 20000;
            System.out.println("sleepingTime:" + sleepingTime);
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(sleepingTime); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            consumer.ack();
            System.out.println("test completed");
        };
        try {
            subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build();
            // Start the subscriber.
            subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
            System.out.printf("Listening for messages on %s:\n", subscriptionName.toString());
            // Allow the subscriber to run for 30s unless an unrecoverable error occurs.
            // subscriber.awaitTerminated(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() throws Exception {
        // Shut down the subscriber after 30s. Stop receiving messages.
        subscriber.stopAsync();
    }

}```

Below is Response
20:53:24,300 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-128) Id: 1288313732423842
20:53:24,300 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-128) Data: abc13
**20:53:24,300 INFO**  [stdout] (Thread-128) sleepingTime:20000
**20:53:44,300 INFO**  [stdout] (Thread-128) test completed
````

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Cloud Pub/Sub client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries), the deadline is automatically extended up to the `MaxAckExtensionPeriod` [specified in the `Subscriber.Buider`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setMaxAckExtensionPeriod-org.threeten.bp.Duration-). This extension period defaults to one hour. To change this value, you'd want to change the line that creates the subscriber as follows:

```
subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver)
    .setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .build();
```